# Assigning int*** to int[][][]

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Pointer of Multi-Dimension Arrays Work in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161247/how-pointer-of-multi-dimension-arrays-work-in-c)

I need an `int***` to point to the value of an `int[][][]`, but when I loop through the rows, cols and layers and assign `ptr[r][c][l]` to `val[r][c][l]`, I get a segmentation fault.

Can someone please show me how to assign an `int***` to an `int[][][]`?

Here is my code:

```
int row=2;
int col=3;
int layer=4;

int arr[2][3][4] = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4} },{ {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4} } };

 char _mode = 'h';

int*** ptr ;


for (int r=0;r<row;r++) 
    {
    for (int c=0;c<col;c++)
        {
         for (int l=0;l<layer;l++)

            {

            ptr[row][col][layer] = arr[row][col][layer];

            }
        }
    }

cout <<findExtreme(ptr, row, col, layer,  _mode)<<endl;
```

And here is the function that is called

```
int findExtreme(int*** arr,int row,int col,int layer, char _mode)
{
int val = 0;



 for (int r=0;r<row;r++)    
    {
    for (int c=0;c<col;c++)
        {
         for (int l=0;l<layer;l++)
            {
            if (_mode == 'h')
                if (arr[r][c][l] > val)
                    val = arr[r][c][l];
            if (_mode == 'l')
                if (arr[r][c][l] < val)
                    val = arr[r][c][l];
            }
        }
    }
    return val;

}
```

Comment: If you post the code you have it will be easier for someone to spot the problem.

Comment: Does your `int[][][]` have the right size?

Comment: What's `int[][][]` ? An array ? Only 1st dimension of an array can be empty

Comment: ooh, another three star programmer.

Comment: Your `int ***` is a jagged array every , `int [][][]` is a multidimensional array, you need to ensure they are the same size

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that. You probably want

```
int val[1][2][3];
int (*ptr)[1][2][3] = &val;
```

Comment: This doesn't work since I need a int*** for the function

Comment: @user1490896 then you are out of luck. You can create a copy of the array with the triple-pointer and pass that.